# kubectl get cs prompt Error from server (Forbidden)

Tags: centos, kubernetes

When run `kubectl get cs` on centos 7 I got below error message.

```
No resources found.
Error from server (Forbidden): componentstatuses is forbidden: 
User "system:node:<server-name>" cannot list componentstatuses at the cluster scope
```

I can confirm the api server is running `kubectl cluster-info`

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://<server-IP>:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://<server-IP>:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Also I have below in `~/.bash_profile`

```
export http_proxy=http://<proxy-server-IP>:3128
export https_proxy=http://<proxy-server-IP>:3128
export no_proxy=$no_proxy,127.0.0.1,localhost,<server-IP>,<server-name>
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
```

Not only `kubectl get cs` yield the error message, `kubectl apply -f kubernetes-dashboard.yaml` yield similar error message

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=secrets", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=Secret"
Name: "kubernetes-dashboard-certs", Namespace: "kube-system"
Object: &{map["kind":"Secret" "metadata":map["labels":map["k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"] "name":"kubernetes-dashboard-certs" "namespace":"kube-system" "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""]] "type":"Opaque" "apiVersion":"v1"]}
from server for: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": 
secrets "kubernetes-dashboard-certs" is forbidden: 
User "system:node:<server-name>" cannot get secrets in the namespace "kube-system": 
no path found to object
```

Answer (score 1):

> `export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`

Is completely incorrect; you are, as the error message is cheerfully trying to inform you, attempting to perform cluster operations as a `Node`, not as one of the Users or `ServiceAccount`s. RBAC is almost explicitly designed to stop you from doing exactly what you are currently doing. You would never want a `Node` to be able to read sensitive credentials nor create arbitrary `Pod`s at cluster scope.

If you want to be all caviler about it, then ssh into a master Node and use the `cluster-admin` credentials usually found in `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` (or a similar file -- depending on how your cluster was provisioned). If you don't already *have* a `cluster-admin` credential, then create an X.509 certificate that is signed by a CA that the apiserver trusts with an Organization (`O=` in X.509 parlance) of `cluster-admin` and then create yourself a `ServiceAccount` (or whatever) with a `ClusterRoleBinding` of `cluster-admin` and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below snippets

1) `sudo su`

2) `kubectl get cs`

Answer (score 0):

after reinstall centos 7 and follow below steps i am able to bring up the master properly

1. install docker-ce and add [proxy](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/)
2. install [kubeadm,kubectl,kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubeadm/)
3. disable firewalld and turn off swap
4. export no_proxy in .bash_profile

   `export no_proxy=$no_proxy,127.0.0.1,localhost,<master-server-name>,<master-server-ip>,10.96.0.0/12,10.244.0.0/16`
5. kubeadm init

   `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=<master-server-ip> --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
    mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
    \cp -f /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
    chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config`
6. test with `kubectl get cs`

   `NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
   scheduler            Healthy   ok
   controller-manager   Healthy   ok
   etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}`

No need to manually install etcd nor export KUBECONFIG.